# Which bi-directional ZeroMQ pattern should I use for multiple clients connecting to a single server?

Tags: c, sockets, zeromq

I have multiple ( 1000s ) of clients connecting to a single server and sending some log data.

The server analyses the data and responds, if necessary.

`PUB`/`SUB` is one directional (monitor example ).
`REQ`/`REP` cannot identify the peer and reply specifically to a peer ( it is more for ACK and such only ).

I need to register these clients, identify them and be able to respond after analysis of their logs.

With sockets, I have the client sockets, after accept and I can respond using that socket and the clients can receive on the same socket that I connected to.

I am not finding such a thing in ZeroMQ in my first week of 0mq.

`ROUTER` socket can print peer's id, but how do I reply to that peer using that id ?

Is there a better way to deal with this?

Answer (score 6):

### None of them -- meaning not a single one !
 <sub>. . . rather use more of 'em with some logic on a higher level of abstraction.</sub> 
Why ?

Because of **Maslow's hammer:**

> <sub>“When the only tool you have *( ... want to use )*
>  is a **hammer**,
>  every problem begins to resemble a **nail**.”</sub>

ZeroMQ is a lovely set of fine-tuned building blocks universally equipped ( as per their neutrality as to what transport-class will be used in the final implementation mix ) that is available for re-using 'em inside one's High-Level Logic of the distributed system design & prototyping.

Thus expecting that the very `PUB`/`SUB`, `PAIR`/`PAIR` or any other Formal Scaleable Communication Archetype Primitive will right match the system requirements is rather missing the core of the benefits, we mortals have received from the genuine Martin SUSTRIK & Pieter HINTJENS' smart messaging Team.

### Proposal

One can imagine a following mock-up concept:

**using:**

- Server `.bind()`-s and handles one `SUB` port, known to all clients, that was subscribed well-enough for receiving all "log"-data to process from all id#-hashed clients ( and ignoring any other ingress of data -- even the older versions of the ZeroMQ implemented a `SUB`-side filtering for the `PUB`/`SUB` archetype would allow for this at an acceptable performance load on the server node ). ( Sure, one may object, there may be also other requirements, so as to better handle or avoid completely DDOS-sort of atacks et al, but let's stay trivial in this mock-up )
- client `.connect()`-s it's `PUB` role, on-demand, and introduces itself to the Server listening on the `SUB`-role + moves log-data and either "hangs" or keeps the line silent (a scaling & performance issues ougth be field-tested prior to deciding this group of architecture issues ).
- server may decide to require some ad-hoc conversation with an id#-hashed specific client, but does not want to have an a-priori port publicly exposed by another `.bind()` associated with a static port#, thus server uses another `.connect()`-ed role, a `PUB`, sending ad-hoc a very short, thus having an acceptable footprint of the system-wide associated overhead, signalling, telegramme to the id#-hashed client ( alike a software manner to initiate a port-knocking security behaviour ), telling it where to `.connect()` to the server and solve the additional tasking et al ( client re-discovery and registration and maintenance is doable this way, so the global scheme meets the stated requirement, not to expose any other port statically exposed to external intruder )
- client has another `.bind()`-ready `SUB` role, subscribed to listening to server id#-hashed signalling announcement + setup instructions, what an appropriate client ought `.connect()`-against-`.bind()` ( while a reversed `.bind()`/`.connect()` scheme requires just a bit extended client re-discovery maintenance ) and upon a server-side signal, such ex-post processing may take place on a separate ( even a one-time used ( a fully disposable ) ) ad-hoc communication infrastructure ( be it an `XREQ`/`XREP` or other bilateral Formal Communication Pattern Archetype or some kind of a smarter-mix of several such, intelligently orchestrated ones ), which does not require server to have a statically exposed port but suffice for an ad-hoc server/client request processing.

### Not happy with the sketched mock-up?  <sup>... no doubts, it's so primitive here</sup>
 The Best Next Step:

**After** *(cit.:)* "**my first week of 0mq**" the best next step one may do is IMHO to get a bit more global view, which may sound complicated for the first few things one tries to code with ZeroMQ, but if you **[at least jump to the page 265](https://hintjens.wdfiles.com/local--files/main:files/cc1pe.pdf)** of the [**[Code Connected, Volume 1]** [available asPdf >>>  http://hintjens.wdfiles.com/local--files/main%3Afiles/cc1pe.pdf ]](https://hintjens.wdfiles.com/local--files/main:files/cc1pe.pdf), if it were not the case of reading step-by-step thereto.

The fastest-ever learning-curve would be to have first an un-exposed view on the
**Fig.60**
 *Republishing Updates* [image: Republishing Updates]
and 
**Fig.62** *HA Clone Server pair for a possible High-availability approach* and then go back to the roots, elements and details.

---

Anyway, enjoy the powers of ZeroMQ
and
**[might find interesting to read other ZeroMQ-related Q/A-s here >>>](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bzeromq%5D)**

Comment: so, " client has another .bind()-ready SUB role " is what I dont want to do. I cannot open the ACL for it, since the existing client (sends log to server and reads on connect socket ) server ( binds to a static port and accepts 1000s of client connections and replies some action now and then) socket communication doesnt require it.

Comment: whats wrong with just this : https://github.com/booksbyus/zguide/blob/master/examples/C/asyncsrv.c

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a `DEALER`/`ROUTER` pattern, which sounds complicated, but that can do a bidirectional communication with some async.

I am still waiting for other answers from people with 0mq experience.

Because, **I do not want** the `DEALER` to `.bind()` to any static port.

Comment: Yes, Dealer/Router is best. Router can bind an receive all the logging info from the Dealers (who'd connect). If a reply is required Router can send it to the right client via the identity frame(s).